# Is there any implicit usage of reflection in Java?

Tags: java

The other day I had an interview, and I was asked if a developer uses reflection often? I said, I only used it when learning about reflection itself, and I don't know any "hidden" usage of it in Java.

I forgot to ask my interviewer later about it. But still, are there any cases, where reflection is used and it's not obvious for a developer?

Comment: What do you mean by "not obvious for a developer"?

Comment: Use of annotations may qualify. A quick search seems to suggest that annotations can rely on reflection.

Comment: Carcigenicate, thank you, I think you're right, and this is the only thing I could google about it, but I wonder if that's all.

Comment: Joe C, by "not obvious for a developer" I mean some encapsulated mechanisms or something in native code, you know - just not obvious

Comment: many popular frameworks use reflection in a "hidden" manner for all sorts of functionalities, such as spring and hybernate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well , AOP is one of the common use-case of reflection which address the cross cutting concerns.

For example, Spring AOP uses dynamic proxy in the reflection package for its implementation under some situation for caching , transaction boundary management , exception handling, executing asynchronous method and etc...

Comment: Thank you, and also Assaf for info on hibernate, that'll be my investigation for a couple of days

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/106363/139641) argues that `instanceof` is reflection because:

> The program observes [the value's] structure and conducts type introspection.

By the same argument, a checked cast is reflection, because that does the same: it's sort of like

```
SomeType s = (SomeType) x;

// is like
if (!(x instanceof SomeType)) {
  throw new ClassCastException();
}
SomeType s = (/* er, some magic that isn't a cast, because I'm saying "this is like a cast" */) x;
```

But casting like that is still doing something explicit. You get implicit casts in generic code:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("hi");
String s = list.get(0);
```

The second line is converted at compile time to:

```
String s = (String) list.get(0);
```

Hence, if you accept casting as a reflective operation, then generic code contains implicit casts.

Comment: wow, thanks, that's a nice one. Haven't thought about it that way. Still a lot to learn

Answer (score 0):

Java reflections are used for example in objects mapping frameworks like ModelMapper. Other use case might be for example frameworks like Spring, where reflections are used to examine classes structure (methods/annotations) when bean definitions are created and in AOP.